# Match a href-class with div-class in if-statement

Tags: jquery

I´d really like some help with this one... I'm building a filterbox for portfolio-items.

I have four links each with one classname, the same as their text. All portfolio items are listed besides. Each portfolio item is in a div with two classes — .listItem AND one of the links classes.

Example: `<a class="Architecture" href="#">`

The div I want to animate on a-click is: `<div class="listItem Architecture">`

This is my script and it´s not working...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var filterTrig = $('#sortPort a').attr('class');

    $('#sortPort a').click(function() {
        $('.listItem').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(filterTrig)){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you want to hide the div with the matching classname or hide all others?

Answer (score 1):

[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) takes a selector. You're working with a class name, so you can use [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sortPort a").click(function() {
        var filterTrig = $(this).attr("class");
        $(".listItem").each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass(filterTrig)) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You could also prefix the class name with a period character (`.`), in order to turn it into a class selector, but that won't work if the anchor element exposes multiple classes.

Comment: Nothing happens... I really don´t get this. Are there any other way to sort out those divs with the same class-names as the links? I´ve tried out with text() as well, trying to match strings from the divs and anchors to makte the animations on the divs without the links classname...

Comment: @Samuel, you're only setting `filterTrig` once, that's probably the problem. See the updated code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I worked more with the code and came up with a diferent way. Its probably huge and ugly written, but the script works. Including all effects, its like this (see it live at 1979design.se/portfolio):Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I worked more with the code and came up with a diferent solution. Its probably huge and ugly written, but the script works for now.

Including all effects, its like this (see it live at 1979design.se/portfolio):

```
var listItem = $('.listItem')
        var sp = 'currentSortPort'  
       $('#sortPort a.filter').bind(
          'click' , function(a) {
              var trigger = $(this).html();
              var portType = '.listItem'+'.'+trigger;
                  $('h3').removeClass(sp);
                  $(a.target).parent().addClass(sp);

              $(listItem).each( function() {
                   $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                  $(portType).addClass('selected');
                  $(this).not('.selected').fadeTo('medium', 0.1);
              });  
              $('.listItem').removeClass('selected');             
         return false;
     });
     $('a.reset').click(function(b){
          $('h3').removeClass(sp);
          $(b.target).parent().addClass(sp);
          $(listItem).fadeTo('fast', 1);
          return false;
     });
```

Thanks again! Youre right, jQuery is not impossible ;)   Only huge scripted when done by newbies